# Generating all variations of certain length out of string

Tags: c#, string, permutation, string-length

I've seen few implementations of variations of string in C#, but none of them had any limitation on their length. Unfortunately, I cannot modify them to achieve my goal which is e.g.

for:

```
string = "ABCD" and variationLength = 2
```

generate new strings:

```
AB, AC, AD, BA, BC, BD, CA, CB, CD, DA, DB, DC
```

I'm looking for exactly this Python's itertools.permutations implementation but in C#. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Is there anything similar to its in C#? If not, then what is the easiest way to implement it?

Edit_2:
so far I came up with an idea to list all unique chars of given string and then get variations out of them

```
static void PrintAllKLengthPerm(string str, int k)
{
    int n = str.Length;
    PrintAllKLengthPermRec(str, "", n, k);
}

// The main recursive method to print all possible strings of length k
static void PrintAllKLengthPermRec(string str, String prefix, int n, int k)
{
    // Base case: k is 0, print prefix
    if (k == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prefix);
        return;
    }

    // One by one add all characters from str and recursively 
    // call for k equals to k-1
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        // Next character of input added
        String newPrefix = prefix + str[i];

        // k is decreased, because we have added a new character
        PrintAllKLengthPermRec(str, newPrefix, n, k - 1);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "ABCD";
    int permLen = 2;

    //get all unique characters in string
    string uniqStr = new String(str.Distinct().ToArray());

    // Print all possible strings of length permLen out of uniqStr characters
    PrintAllKLengthPerm(uniqStr, permLen);      
}
```

However I am looking for more optimal and effective solution

Comment: Please show your work. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Soviut edited..

Comment: @JayDouble That's not showing your work. Actually make an attempt and show the code so that we can help you. I understand you're new here so I wanted to clarify that SO isn't an advice forum nor is it a place that writes code for you; We help you solve problems with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a truly recursive permutation method:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Permutate(string source, int count)
{
    if (source.Length == 1)
    {
        yield return source;
    }
    else if (count == 1)
    {
        for (var n = 0; n < source.Length; n++)
        {
            yield return source.Substring(n, 1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (var n = 0; n < source.Length; n++)
            foreach (var suffix in Permutate(
                source.Substring(0, n)
                    + source.Substring(n + 1, source.Length - n - 1), count -1))
            {
                yield return source.Substring(n, 1) + suffix;
            }
    }
}
```

It can be called with `Permutate("ABCD", 2)` and returns this:

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> newPermutations = new List<string>();
for(int a = 0; a!=inString.Count; a++)
    for((int b = 0; b!=inString.Count; b++)
        if(noRepetitions && a == b) continue;
        newPermutations.Add(""+inString[a] + inString[b]);
```

I think that that should work; I am still trying to figure out a way to not only have 2 letters.

Edit: Edited it to work, the old one just didn't work... lol
Edit: Thanks to @Bloopy, they helped me spot some errors in my for loops

Comment: To have a `permutationLength` variable that can be changed, perhaps you could look at creating an array with that no. of dimensions and then looping through those. Two points though: if you changed `foreach` to `for` and used ints `i` & `j` (checking `i != j`), then your solution would work for permutations of strings with duplicate elements. Also, you need to convert `a` to a string as `a + b` on chars adds their integer values.

Comment: @Bloopy 1. How could one choose a number of dimensions... I've thought about it before but an idea has never come to mine (Neither have I ever done any real research.) 2. The `i` & `j` approach is a great idea, and 3. `""+a+b` would work. Thanks for the improvement!

Comment: I looked into it more and I realised it'd get even more complicated than my existing answer. However, I did figure out an alternative way using LINQ which I've added as an alternative. By the way, you forgot to increment your for variables and you've added 3 more compilation errors to your code!!

Answer (score 1):

I made the following recursive function which accomplishes your task:

```
static void Permutations(List<string> output, string str, int n, string curr)
    {
        if(curr.Length == n)
        {
            output.Add(curr);
            return;
        }
        foreach(char c in str)
            if(!curr.Contains(c.ToString()))
                Permutations(output, str, n, curr + c.ToString());
    }
```

and then you call it like this:

```
string str = "ABCD";
int length = 2;
List<string> perms = new List<string>();
Permutations(perms, str, length, "");
// now the list "perms" will contain the permutations of "str" in length "n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using modulo and division. There are 4² possible strings of length 2 using the letters ABCD. Number them from 0 to 4²-1 and repeatedly divide each number by 4. Use the resulting remainders as array indexes on the ABCD string.

This has the advantage of allowing you to keep the strings with repeated elements (AA, BB, CC, DD) when needed – just skip the discard step.

```
string alphabet = "ABCD";
int length = 2;

int[] indexes = new int[length];
char[] item = new char[length];

// loop through all possible strings for the given alphabet and length
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Pow(alphabet.Length, length); i++) {

    int dividend = i;
    for (int j = length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        indexes[j] = dividend % alphabet.Length;
        dividend /= alphabet.Length;
    }

    // discard any that use the same alphabet element more than once
    if (indexes.Distinct().Count() < length)
        continue;

    for (int k = 0; k < length; k++) {
        item[k] = alphabet[indexes[k]];
    }

    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Alternatively, here's a really brief solution using LINQ. Note that this one doesn't work correctly if there are duplicate elements in the string (unless you want to remove the call to `Where` and keep the AA, BB etc.). I'd need to track the indexes like I did in my method above.

```
IEnumerable<string> prm = alphabet.Select(c => c.ToString());
for (int a = 1; a < length; a++)
    prm = prm.SelectMany(s => alphabet.Where(t => !s.Contains(t)), (x, y) => x + y);

foreach (string s in prm)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```